# String Not Working As Table Name - Access VBA -

Tags: ms-access, vba

The beginning of the following code is supposed to get the BaseName of a file name in a textbox on a form and set it equal to a String "tblnewbid". The Debug.Print tblnew bid prints out the correct Table name exactly as it is supposed to. I verified the characters match exactly and there is an actual table that matches that name.

When I run the code I get error: Cannot find table or constraint. If I manually change tblnew to the actual table name, the code runs fine. Could it be that I need to Dim tblnewbid as something other than string?

```
Private Sub btnInsertRegions_Click()

DoCmd.Hourglass True  ' turn on Hourglass


Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim tblnewbid As String

Set db = CurrentDb
tblnewbid = FSO.GetBaseName(Me.txtFileName)


Debug.Print tblnewbid

db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblnewbid ADD COLUMN O_StateRegion CHAR", dbFailOnError
db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblnewbid ADD COLUMN D_StateRegion CHAR", dbFailOnError

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [OriginState] from [tblnewbid];")

rs.MoveFirst

    strSQL = "UPDATE [tblnewbid] INNER JOIN [tblStates]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " ON [tblStates].[StateAbbrev] = [tblnewbid].[OriginState]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " SET [tblnewbid].[O_StateRegion]=[tblStates].[StateRegion]"


    db.Execute (strSQL), dbFailOnError


rs.MoveFirst

    strSQL = "UPDATE [tblnewbid] INNER JOIN [tblStates]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " ON [tblStates].[StateAbbrev] = [tblnewbid].[DestinationState]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " SET [tblnewbid].[D_StateRegion]=[tblStates].[StateRegion]"


    db.Execute (strSQL), dbFailOnError

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you place a variable inside double quotes, it stops being a variable and becomes a literal string.

What you want to do instead is have the variable evaluated and then placed inside of the string. You can do this with concatenation:

ie:

```
db.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & tblnewbid & " ADD COLUMN O_StateRegion CHAR", dbFailOnError
```

Apply this concatenation to each line that needs to evaluate your variable.

Comment: That definitely got me past that error. Thank you very much. However, once I read your answer, it made sense that I would need to do this throughout the rest of the code. (see end of this comment) But when I do, I get and error on the next line that says: too few parameters. Expected 1. 'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [OriginState] from " & tblnewbid & " ; ")' Any thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind. I found the error in the actual table. A field name was incorrect. I haven't run the code yet, but I'm sure it will work fine.

Comment: It did indeed run perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I should have been more clear about applying that throughout your code. Glad I could help!